# Rails: DRY Views for Role Based Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, dry

I'm curious what the state of the art is for DRY views these days. I've got an app that's been evolving for over three and a half years, and these days the view layer is not a happy place.

First a little background, I've got an app that is used by several different groups of users, and I need to add more. There is a significant amount of overlap between what different users see, but there's still a lot that is exclusive to each group. Users have restrictions what and how much detail they see. It's your standard role based web app.

Currently the app is using an ugly mishmash of partials (with local variables), and partials using partials, content_for blocks and helpers, and a whole bunch of duplication.

What I'm looking for is, what are people doing these days to keep their views DRY?

I started looking at Cells (http://cells.rubyforge.org/), but I wondered, what else is out there for solving this problem.

What are you using for complex and role-based views?

Comment: I dont think that a general answer exists.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same problem/challenge. I've started implementing Cell but ran into a wall, 'content_for' is not supported in the way you'd expect and it is not possible to add content to the master layout with it using a cell view.

This is a limitation in Rails / the way Cell uses rails and is not really circumventable it seems.

If you can live with this limitation I think it is the best solution for repeated content blocks.

Slightly offtopic the best solution to the above problem for me is the following:

If the entire cell needs to be rendered in a different content block the following can be used to get a nice api:

Put the following piece of code in the application_helper.rb:

```
def render_cell_for(id, cell, action, options = nil, &block)
  content_for id do
    render_cell(cell, action, options, &block)
  end
end
```

Use

```
<%=render_cell_for(:content_for, :cell, :action) %>
```

in your views to render within a content for block.